# TortoiseSVN - Can a copy of checked out (i.e. - a copy of the working copy) files be checked in?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a copy of a working copy (i.e. - checked out) of the files from our repository. Is it possible to check in the copy of the working copy, or will that cause conflicts and errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied the whole working copy (including the .svn folder) the copy is a working copy just like the original working copy. So you can commit, update, etc. just like from every other working copy.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the feedback.